# Insert wrong date in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb

I am tring to save dates in my MongoDB table using C#.

Here is a JavaScript logic that send data using Ajax to C# controller

```
$(function ($, w, d) {
    var _user = {}
    //var time =    moment("2016-04-02", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow()
    //var bime =    moment().endOf('day').fromNow();
    //var crime =   moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
    //              document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
    var obj = {};
    var holidaylist = ["Mar-31-2018", "Apr-01-2018","Apr-04-2018","Apr-07-2018","Apr-08-2018"];
    var  startdate = new Date("Apr-02-2018");

    obj.endDate = "Apr-06-2018";
    obj.holidaylist = holidaylist;
    obj.NumberOfCount = 9;
    CallAjax("POST", '/LeaveManagement/', 'checkleavelogic', obj, onsuccessaddemployee, '');
```

here is the C# logic that saves the data in MongoDB:

```
public JsonResult checkLeaveLogic(LeaveLogicModel leaveLogic)
{
    string strconnectiomstring = "mongodb://10.10.32.125:27017";
    MongoClient Client = new MongoClient(strconnectiomstring);
    var DB = Client.GetDatabase("TimeClock");

    List<DateTime> leavesDate = new List<DateTime>();
    var collection = DB.GetCollection<LeaveLogicModel>("leaves1");
    collection.InsertOne(leaveLogic);
}
```

Now this is the MongoDB table that saves as a previous date.

[image: Mongodb DataBase Record]

Here you can see that my `StartDate` is **Apr-02-2018** but it saves as **Apr-01-2018** and for all date it is the same.

Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: It's not Apr-01-2018, it's Apr-01-2018 18:30:00Z, this means there is a 5 hour 30 minute offset between your localtime and UTC.

Comment: what i have to do For Correct Date

Comment: It is considered good practice to always store dates and times as UTC letting your UI worry about the conversion, which will probably happen automatically in the browser.

Comment: It is stored as the correct date, just a different representation of it.

Answer (score 2):

When you create new dates with just date or date and time, it usually creates them in the same timezone as the program is.

So if you dont specify the timezone, it becomes the timezone the server is in. When you save to Mongo, the Date is serialized to UTC -> zero timezone.

Create the dates with +00:00 timezone and you should have consistent data.

Comment: how can i add timezone in my date

Comment: Follow ISO 8601 format - https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime -> for example `2018-04-05T08:15:30+00:00 `. But also be aware that when you take the date from database, most libraries will try to modify it back to your timezone. With i.e. moment (npm library), you can call `.utc()` method to force the zero-timezone

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to set your datetimes to UTC, however if you want to convert it, you can use something like this.

```
       var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
       TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Comment: How can i Convert It on Insert Time In Mongodb

Comment: @ChitraNandpal what do you mean?, you just need to run this for the object, before you exeucte  collection.InsertOne(leaveLogic);

Comment: ok,But What i Have To Write In Second Parameter I Means In TimeZone

Comment: "write in second parameter", sorry what do you mean?

Comment: i means what is the value of  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(leaveLogic.start_date, timeZone); <- timeZone Parameter

Comment: i tried with start date but it is giving me same result 2018-04-01 18:30:00.000Z